# I don't understand the meaning/usage of prePostEnabled

Tags: spring

I referred the following pages [Page1](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security) and [Page2](https://dzone.com/articles/securing-spring-data-rest-with-preauthorize) but couldn't understand the meaning/usage/purpose of prePostEnabled - with value false and true

Could someone please explain.

What is prePostEnabled is?

Thanks

Comment: This enables processing of `@PreAuthorize`/`@PreFilter` and `@PostAuthorize`/`@PostFilter`. Without enabling it the annotations mean nothing.